# Installing Gerrit on Linux | unknown key type ed25519

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to install Gerrit on a linux server, I downloaded the war file and run the command

```
java -jar gerrit*.war init --batch --dev -d ~/Gerrit/gerrit_testsite
```

and this is the output

```
Generating SSH host key ... ed25519...unknown key type ed25519
ecdsa 256...Bits has bad value 256 (too small)
ecdsa 384...Bits has bad value 384 (too small)
ecdsa 521...Bits has bad value 521 (too small)
done
Initialized /home/myUser/Gerrit/gerrit_testsite
Reindexing projects:    100% (2/2)
Reindexed 2 documents in projects index in 0.2s (11.0/s)
```

instead of what is shown in the installation guide (https://www.gerritcodereview.com/linux-quickstart.html) :

```
Generating SSH host key ... rsa(simple)... done
Initialized /home/gerrit/gerrit_testsite
Executing /home/gerrit/gerrit_testsite/bin/gerrit.sh start
Starting Gerrit Code Review: OK
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem here ?